# Outlook Task Scheduler to Run Access Subs

Tags: vba, ms-access, outlook

I have Access Macros that run a series of queries, form a tables, and send those tables to multiple recipients. This works fine, but I'm being increasingly asked to supply an increasing number of reports on a set day of the week.

Rather than use my calendar to remind me to open Access and run these Macros, can I run VBA in Outlook to run an Access macro on a certain day?

Comment: user schdule task manager with batch file .BAT to run macro in access. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20245053/running-microsoft-access-as-a-scheduled-task

Answer (score 1):

> Rather than use my calendar to remind me to open Access and run these Macros, can I run VBA in Outlook to run an Access macro on a certain day?

There are ways you can do this with .BAT files and windows task scheduler, but you can also do it with Outlook VBA. I have a few calendar events which have this exact purpose, to execute code and clear the reminder.

First you need to add an event handler to fire when your reminders get set.

```
Private WithEvents olRemind As Outlook.Reminders
```

You then need to initialize the `WithEvents`. I do this everytime a reminder happens because I sometimes break code or hard stop, which loses the event handler.

```
Private Sub Application_Reminder(ByVal Item As Object)
    Set olRemind = Outlook.Reminders
End Sub
```

Then, you want to process the event on your calendar. The way I have mine setup is I add a specific category for the event I want to fire. This helps make my calendar clearer. You can do this in a variety of ways.

I also then dismiss the reminder so it doesn't show up.

```
'fire off automatic macros based on recurring reminders
Private Sub olRemind_BeforeReminderShow(Cancel As Boolean)
    Dim objRem As Reminder

    For Each objRem In olRemind
        'get categories
        Dim rmdrCategories As String

        rmdrCategories = objRem.Item.categories

        'call the macro based on category
        If InStr(rmdrCategories, "whateverYouWantTheReminder") > 0 Then

            'only run if this reminder is visible
            If objRem.IsVisible Then

                'This code is specific to whatever macro you want to run
                Dim mydb As Object                
                Set mydb = GetObject("...pathToDatabase.mdb")
                mydb.Application.Run "YourMacroName"
                mydb.Application.Quit
                Set mydb = Nothing


                 objRem.Dismiss
                Cancel = True
            End If

        End If

    Next objRem

End Sub
```