# Access Macro does not execute from batch file

Tags: batch-file, ms-access

I have a batch file set up in Task Scheduler. However, the access macro it is supposed to run does not. The code is.

```
N:\stufftorun\Thisdb.accdb /x "mac_to_Run"
N:\stufftorun\StuffCombine.bat
exit
```

I'm new to batch files and any resources would be greatly appreciated as well.

Comment: Can you post the code that's giving you the trouble?

Comment: This is the one that is giving me trouble.        N:\stufftorun\Thisdb.accdb /x "mac_to_Run"      N:\stufftorun\StuffCombine.bat      exit

Comment: Checkout this answer: [Running Microsoft Access as a scheduled task](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20245053/running-microsoft-access-as-a-scheduled-task)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clear the quotes:

```
N:\stufftorun\Thisdb.accdb /x mac_to_Run
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it was clearing the quotes or because the Access Application was running on an unmapped drive. At any rate it is working now.