# How to export MS Access table in text file

Tags: mysql, batch-file, ms-access, database-migration

i am interested is it possible to create automated script to export single table from MS Access database in text file, and after that to have other script to automated import that text file in MySQL database, or maybe there is some better way to solve this kind of problem ? Also, server where is MS Access is running on windows , and MySQL service is working on Linux distribution CentOS. Thanks.

Comment: Automated export on what basis? (time, some sort of event etc)?

Comment: @P.Salmon every day at a specified time

Comment: Here's a starter http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20245053/running-microsoft-access-as-a-scheduled-task

Comment: @P.Salmon thank you! How can i now automate this macro? Is it possible to automate process from task schedule, and if answer is yes, how ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [jet-tool](https://bitbucket.org/himselfv/jet-tool/downloads) to get SQL dump of `.mdb` file.

```
jet dump -f Your.mdb >dump.sql
```

Then import `dump.sql` by means of MySQL.

Comment: sry, but what is jet-tool ?

Comment: This tool lets you dump MS Access/MS Jet database schema as an SQL file containing the commands needed to recreate the database from the scratch.

Comment: Does not support the accdb format, as in [.accdb support?](https://bitbucket.org/himselfv/jet-tool/issues/7/accdb-support#comment-37285824).

Comment: The jet-tool utility is good. However, it is need to understand that jet-tool will not make a clean MySQL dump. It will be necessary to adapt (do batch text replacements) in the resulting dump.

Answer (score 0):

I guess these two databases don't talk, or you should be able to export from MS Access and send the job straight to MY SQL.  Is that right?  Here is a script to do the export from Access to a text file.

```
Public Sub ExportTable()
   DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputTable, "tblCustomer", acFormatTXT, _
   "C:\BegVBA\Customer.txt"
End Sub
```

I haven't used MY SQL in a couple of years at least, and I don't have it setup on my machine now.  Anyway, I think it would be something like this.

```
LOAD DATA INFILE '/tmp/mydata.txt' INTO TABLE PerformanceReport;
```

If that doesn't do the trick, you can easily Google it and figure it out yourself.