# Using ms-access command-line tag /x but database opens read-only

Tags: ms-access, command-line

I'm simply trying to run an Access macro through the command line using the command:

```
"C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Office/root/Office16/MSACCESS.EXE" "C:/Users/evans/Documents/Book Business/Building Reports/Book Business.accdb" /x UpdateActiveSKUs
```

I've looked at this question ([Running Microsoft Access as a Scheduled Task](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20245053/running-microsoft-access-as-a-scheduled-task)) but it is not working for me because the Access window opens but is read-only; therefore the macro does not execute. The macro works if I run it myself in the program. I don't understand why it is opening as read-only because I am the only person with access to it and I've triple-checked that it's closed, even restarted the computer. How do I run a macro through the command line?

Comment: Are you running the command line invocation using your own Windows account, as opposed to a built-in Windows account like `LOCAL SERVICE`? "Trusted Locations" in Office are (mostly) user-specific, so opening the database from a different account could have different results depending on "who" was opening it.

Comment: Yes. Try using the folder `C:\Users\Public`.